# Corda - PageSpecification in QueryBy

Tags: java, blockchain, smartcontracts, corda, vault

In R3 Corda queryBy(), is page specification, other than default-200 is only needed, if there are more results to be returned based on given querycriteria

OR

It is needed even if all criterias not match while querying, but has more than 200 of that particular state present in vault and it do a bulk filtering inside ?

For eg:
I need to get CARState of a uniqueID, suppose we have 1000 carstates available in vault. So inorder to get one CarState matching customVaultQueryCriteria() with id, does it need to mention explicit PageSpecification input?

Or only it is needed only for getAllCarStates() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vault query gets translated into an SQL query internally and run on the database. The pagination is only relevant if the result of that query is larger than the page size.

Comment: Thanks. May I also know behaviour of trackBy with this? Like would it throw this pagination exception if the state which tracks is more than 200 on node startup?